# Replace DLL in an application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

We have a customer that have an application that interacts with a device using a dll developed by one of our vendors. We have to replace this dll because we want to release a new device, but our client don't want to recompile because he don't want to have two versions of the same application. How can I replace the DLL without assembly reference error?

Thanks.

Comment: I had it working by simply replacing the dll file in the directory, that if you export them externally to the .exe

Comment: if the dependency changes its api, then you will have to upgrade everything.

Comment: Is the assembly signed? If so there´s no way in doing what you want, as the public key of your vendor will surely be different from yours. Otherwise it should work until you´re changing the public API (e.g. add a new method, change signatures, ..).

Answer (score 4):

For this to work:

The original dll should not be [signed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-sign-an-assembly-with-a-strong-name), otherwise you will not be able to give your replacement exactly the same identity (so referencing assemblies will not recognise the replacement). The only way around this would be to sign your replacement with the same snk (Strong Name Key) file as used by your vendor - that is they would have to give you their snk file, which is extremely inadvisable (any vendor willing to do this should be avoided!).

The replacement dll needs to provide the same public API as the original dll.

The replacement dll should have the same version number as the original, or you should use a [bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element) in the application's config file to tell .Net to load your new dll with a different version number:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <dependentAssembly>  
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"  
                          publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
                          culture="neutral" />  
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"  
                         newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>  
         </dependentAssembly>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```